# Update Apollo Client auth link after creation

Tags: javascript, apollo-client

I am authenticating requests to my server via Apollo Client using a token and have copied the following example provided in the docs:

```
const httpLink = createHttpLink({ uri: 'http://0.0.0.0:3003' });

const authLink = setContext((_, { headers }) => {
  // get the authentication token from local storage if it exists
  const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
  // return the headers to the context so httpLink can read them
  return {
    headers: {
      ...headers,
      authorization: token ? `Bearer ${token}` : '',
    },
  };
});

const apolloClient = new ApolloClient({
  link: authLink.concat(httpLink),
});
```

This works great, but eventually the token will expire and I'll need to update the token in use by Apollo Client.

How would I do that without instantiating a new Apollo Client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found more than one way to resolve this using Apollo Links.

The method I went with (because of the way my app's authentication is structured) was to use the [`setContext` method from `apollo-link-context`](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/link/links/context/#Usage).

e.g.

```
import { setContext } from "apollo-link-context";
import { from } from 'apollo-link';

const authMiddleware = setContext((operation, { headers }) => {
  return getToken().then(data => {
    return {
      headers: {
        ...headers,
        authorization: `Bearer ${data.token}` || null,
      }
    };
  });
});

const apolloClient = new ApolloClient({
  link: from([authMiddleware, httpLink]),
  cache,
});
```

Now every time a request is made a token is set on the headers. Be careful when writing the getToken function so that a call for a new token is not made every time a request is made to Apollo.

There is also a [specific Link for refreshing tokens](https://github.com/newsiberian/apollo-link-token-refresh).